# Comments in CocoaPods?

Tags: cocoapods

Is there a way to write a comment inside a CocoaPod file? I had a look at their [CocoaPods Guide](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html), but I couldn't see anything.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can add comments in a Podfile by using the Ruby comment syntax:

**Inline**

```
#comment
```

**Block**

```
=begin
all my comments..
=end
```